# Convert Arc to segments for Polygonize

Tags: .net, geometry, autocad, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to convert an arc to line segments in AutoCAD as per the image below.

I would like to run the polygonize function in net topology suite to count all enclosed areas and I haven't found a way of doing this without only using line segments.

Is there a way that I can easily convert an Arc to N number of edges? or, am I able to pass an Arc to polygonize some how?

[image: Convert Arc to line segments]

Answer (score 1):

Polylines, like other curves, have the method `getPointOnDist`, which will give You points on the arc segment. Then You need to insert vertex for polyline in points. In the end, You need to `setBulgeAt` to 0 for each inserted vertex to convert arc segments to line segments.